# basic about pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to declare an array of pointers of a `struct` `some_struct` in C

Can I do:

```
some_struct* arr[10];
```

instead of:

```
some_struct** arr=(some_struct**)malloc(10*sizeof(some_struct*));
```

And what's the difference?

Comment: Please don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: @mikithskegg because `void*` can be implicitly converted to any other pointer type, and if you manually cast the return value, when you change the type to `some_other_struct` you will have to change the cast as well

Comment: The cast is only required in C++. But in C++, you should be using `new` instead of `malloc()`.

Comment: @mikithskegg: Why *not*? Why *would* you cast anything?? Mystical: That comment is too much apples-and-pears for my liking...

Comment: @SethCarnegie Thanks that's helpful!

Comment: It's frustrating to see that even after all this time, none of the answers can give a pure-C explanation that doesn't involve unnecessary implementation details.

Comment: @KerrekSB this is C, we like implementation details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The first one puts the array on the stack.
- The second one allocates it on the heap.

In the first case, the lifetime of the array is only the scope at which it is defined in. 
When it falls out of scope, it will be freed automatically so you don't have to do any clean up.

In the second case, the array lives beyond the scope where the pointer is declared. So you will need to manually `free()` it later to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: automatic storage/dynamic storage. :) +1 nevertheless

Comment: C doesn't really have "lifetime", though, does it? It's only about the validity of the allocated memory. Automatic memory is released automatically, while dynamic memory has to be released manually.

Comment: Was trying to keep the explanation simple. Pedantic terminology tends to confuse beginners.

Comment: @Mysticial: On the contrary, needless details clutter the mind and confuse. What's important is how the different types of memory *behave*, not how they're implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The first is allocated on the stack.

- Its lifetime is the surrounding scope, and you don't have to manually deallocate the memory it occupies since it will be deallocated when the enclosing scope ends (it is said to have an **automatic** storage duration)
- Compile-time arrays like this must have a constant size (that is, the size must be known at compile time, not runtime. Unless you are using C99 which allows Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) or the GCC compiler which has a non-standard extension to allow that
- Once they are created, they cannot be resized

The second is allocated on the heap.

- Its lifetime is until you manually deallocate it with `free` (it is said to have **dynamic** storage duration)
- If you don't use `free` on it before you lose all pointers to it (in this case, before the pointer to it goes out of scope), you will have a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
- The size of these arrays can be determined at runtime
- You can use `realloc` on the pointer to the array to ask the C runtime to try to make it bigger (or smaller) in place (or move it to a different larger area of memory if resizing it in place is not possible)

Comment: Do you mean *can't* be determined at runtime?

Comment: @Marlon no, the size of dynamic arrays can be determined at runtime because allocation is done at runtime by the `malloc` function, not the compiler

Answer (score 0):

The first one will be allocated in the stack, the second in the heap

Answer (score 0):

`some_struct* arr[10];` Will allocate the memory on the stack, while `some_struct** arr=(some_struct*)malloc(10*sizeof(some_struct*));` will allocate it on the heap.